# Change side wallpapers between pages

Tags: page-breaking, wallpaper

My document has graphics on its left and right border on each page, I use the package `wallpaper` for that:

```
\newcommand{\dsaSetDefaultPageBorders}{
   \ULCornerWallPaper{}{./fanpaket/balken-links.png}
   \URCornerWallPaper{}{./fanpaket/balken-rechts.png}
}
\dsaSetDefaultPageBorders
```

I define an environment for a title page, which should have different borders:

```
\newenvironment{dsaTitlePage}{
   \ClearWallPaper
   \ThisULCornerWallPaper{}{./fanpaket/balken-symbole-links.png}
   \ThisURCornerWallPaper{}{./fanpaket/balken-symbole-rechts.png}
   % other stuff
}{
   % other stuff
   \pagebreak
   \dsaSetDefaultPageBorders
}
```

On the title page that gets produced by this, *both* border image sets are used on top of each other. If I remove `\dsaSetDefaultPageBorders` from the environment, this doesn't happen, but then there are no borders at all in the following document. How can I fix this? And why isn't there a `\ThisClearWallPaper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing `\pagebreak` to `\newpage`.